# Why do I have to add type when declaring variables that are structs defined with generics?

Tags: generics, struct, rust

I have the following code to which I tried to apply generics.

```
fn main() {
    
let HALVING2016: When= When {
        year: 2016.0,
    month: 7.0,
    day: 9.0,
    };
    
let HIGH2017: When= When {
        year: 2017.0,
    month: 12.0,
    day: 20.0,
    };

let HALVING2020: When= When {
        year: 2020.0,
    month: 5.0,
    day: 18.0,
    };


let DAYS_IN_Y: f32 = 365.25;

let DAYS_IN_M: f32 = 30.43757;

    
let NO_OF_DAYS_FROM_YEARS: f32 =   (HIGH2017.year - HALVING2016.year) * DAYS_IN_Y ; 

let NO_OF_DAYS_FROM_MONTHS: f32 =   (HIGH2017.month - HALVING2016.month) * DAYS_IN_M ; //This number can be negative!

let NO_OF_DAYS_FROM_DAYS: f32 = HIGH2017.day - HALVING2016.day ; //This number can be negative!


let DAYS_ALLTOGETHER: f32 = NO_OF_DAYS_FROM_YEARS + NO_OF_DAYS_FROM_MONTHS + NO_OF_DAYS_FROM_DAYS;

let MONTHS_ALLTOGETHER: f32 = DAYS_ALLTOGETHER / DAYS_IN_M ;


let DAYS_FROM_DM: f32 = DAYS_ALLTOGETHER - DAYS_IN_Y ;



    
let high2021: When= When {
    year: HALVING2020.year + (MONTHS_ALLTOGETHER) / 12.0,
    month: DAYS_FROM_DM / DAYS_IN_M + 5.0 ,
    day: 20.0 + NO_OF_DAYS_FROM_DAYS ,
    
    };  

let low2015: Low = Low {
    high: 1128.4, 
    low: 197.84 ,
    percentage: (1128.4 - 197.84 ) / 1128.4,
};  
    
println!("The all-time high for Bitcoin will happen on {:.0}/{:.0}/{:.0} i.e. {:.1} months from its halving in May of 2020.", high2021.day, high2021.month, high2021.year, MONTHS_ALLTOGETHER );


let low2018: Low = Low {
    high: 19798.6, 
    low: 3156.2, //13/12/2018 the same date as XMR
    percentage: (19798.6 - 3156.2 ) / 19798.6,
};

let low2022: Low = Low {
    high: ( low2018.high / 1128.4 ) * low2018.high , //We do not have the data for the ATH of XMR that corresponds to BTC 1128.4
    low: (1.0 - 0.8326284) * ( low2018.high / 1128.4 ) * low2018.high,
    percentage: (0.82467216 + 0.8405847 ) / 2.0,
};

println!("The all-time high of ${:.0} for Bitcoin was followed by the drop of {:.1}%.", low2015.high, low2015.percentage * 100.0 );

println!("The last all-time high of {:.0} for Bitcoin was followed by the drop of {:.1}%.", low2018.high, low2018.percentage * 100.0 );

println!("The high of 2017 was {:.2} times higher than the high of 2014. The average of the last two corrections is {:.1}%.\n", low2022.high / low2018.high, low2022.percentage * 100.0 );

println!("Should the high of 2021 be {:.2} times higher than the high of 2017 it would be at the price of ${:.0}.", low2022.high / low2018.high, low2022.high );

println!("Should the correction in the 2022-2023 be that of {:.2}% from the top of {:.0}, the bottom would be at ${:.0}.\n", low2022.percentage * 100.0, low2022.high, low2022.low );

}



struct When{
    year: f32,
    month: f32,
    day: f32,
}

struct Low {
    high: f32,
    low: f32,
    percentage: f32  
}
```

For start I tried
to use generics in struct definitions by replacing the definition of the struct `When`:

```
struct When<T>{
    year: T,
    month: T,
    day: T,
}
```

Then, when I run it I get the messages from the compiler:

```
error[E0107]: missing generics for struct `When`
  --> src/main.rs:3:18
   |
3  | let HALVING2016: When = When {
   |                  ^^^^ expected 1 type argument
   |
note: struct defined here, with 1 type parameter: `T`
  --> src/main.rs:86:8
   |
86 | struct When<T>{
   |        ^^^^ -
help: use angle brackets to add missing type argument
   |
3  | let HALVING2016: When<T> = When {
```

Following the suggestions of the compiler I added missing type arguments (`<T>`), so that the code now looks like that:

```
fn main() {
    
let HALVING2016: When<T> = When {
        year: 2016.0,
    month: 7.0,
    day: 9.0,
    };
    
let HIGH2017: When<T> = When {
        year: 2017.0,
    month: 12.0,
    day: 20.0,
    };

let HALVING2020: When<T> = When {
        year: 2020.0,
    month: 5.0,
    day: 18.0,
    };


let DAYS_IN_Y: f32 = 365.25;

let DAYS_IN_M: f32 = 30.43757;

    
let NO_OF_DAYS_FROM_YEARS: f32 =   (HIGH2017.year - HALVING2016.year) * DAYS_IN_Y ; 

let NO_OF_DAYS_FROM_MONTHS: f32 =   (HIGH2017.month - HALVING2016.month) * DAYS_IN_M ; //This number can be negative!

let NO_OF_DAYS_FROM_DAYS: f32 = HIGH2017.day - HALVING2016.day ; //This number can be negative!


let DAYS_ALLTOGETHER: f32 = NO_OF_DAYS_FROM_YEARS + NO_OF_DAYS_FROM_MONTHS + NO_OF_DAYS_FROM_DAYS;

let MONTHS_ALLTOGETHER: f32 = DAYS_ALLTOGETHER / DAYS_IN_M ;


let DAYS_FROM_DM: f32 = DAYS_ALLTOGETHER - DAYS_IN_Y ;
    
let high2021: When<T> = When {
    year: HALVING2020.year + (MONTHS_ALLTOGETHER) / 12.0,
    month: DAYS_FROM_DM / DAYS_IN_M + 5.0 ,
    day: 20.0 + NO_OF_DAYS_FROM_DAYS ,
    
    };  

let low2015: Low = Low {
    high: 1128.4, 
    low: 197.84 ,
    percentage: (1128.4 - 197.84 ) / 1128.4,
};  
    
println!("The all-time high for Bitcoin will happen on {:.0}/{:.0}/{:.0} i.e. {:.1} months from its halving in May of 2020.", high2021.day, high2021.month, high2021.year, MONTHS_ALLTOGETHER );


let low2018: Low = Low {
    high: 19798.6, 
    low: 3156.2, //13/12/2018 the same date as XMR
    percentage: (19798.6 - 3156.2 ) / 19798.6,
};

let low2022: Low = Low {
    high: ( low2018.high / 1128.4 ) * low2018.high , //We do not have the data for the ATH of XMR that corresponds to BTC 1128.4
    low: (1.0 - 0.8326284) * ( low2018.high / 1128.4 ) * low2018.high,
    percentage: (0.82467216 + 0.8405847 ) / 2.0,
};

println!("The all-time high of ${:.0} for Bitcoin was followed by the drop of {:.1}%.", low2015.high, low2015.percentage * 100.0 );

println!("The last all-time high of {:.0} for Bitcoin was followed by the drop of {:.1}%.", low2018.high, low2018.percentage * 100.0 );

println!("The high of 2017 was {:.2} times higher than the high of 2014. The average of the last two corrections is {:.1}%.\n", low2022.high / low2018.high, low2022.percentage * 100.0 );

println!("Should the high of 2021 be {:.2} times higher than the high of 2017 it would be at the price of ${:.0}.", low2022.high / low2018.high, low2022.high );

println!("Should the correction in the 2022-2023 be that of {:.2}% from the top of {:.0}, the bottom would be at ${:.0}.\n", low2022.percentage * 100.0, low2022.high, low2022.low );

}


struct When<T>{
    year: T,
    month: T,
    day: T,
}


struct Low {
    high: f32,
    low: f32,
    percentage: f32  
}
```

and this time I get the following messages from the compiler:

```
error[E0412]: cannot find type `T` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:3:23
  |
3 | let HALVING2016: When<T> = When {
  |                       ^ not found in this scope

error[E0412]: cannot find type `T` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:9:20
  |
9 | let HIGH2017: When<T> = When {
  |                    ^ not found in this scope

error[E0412]: cannot find type `T` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:15:23
   |
15 | let HALVING2020: When<T> = When {
   |                       ^ not found in this scope

error[E0412]: cannot find type `T` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:44:20
   |
44 | let high2021: When<T> = When {
   |                    ^ not found in this scope
```

I'm stuck. Why did I have to add ? [In an example
from this textbook](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-01-syntax.html) their code works just fine without them.

P.S. I am well aware of breaching the convention when it comes to naming
my variables with capitals, but let this be outside of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do things slightly different when you're *defining* a struct, and when you're *instantiating* a struct.

When you write:

```rust
struct When<T>{
    year: T,
    month: T,
    day: T,
}
```

You're saying "There is going to be a type, we'll call it `T`, I don't know what that type will be, but you'll know what it is when this struct is instantiated". `T` is like a placeholder.

When you're instantiating the type, you can't just say it's a `When<T>` any more - the compiler needs to know what type is filling that placeholder called `T`.

There are three ways you can do that in your code:

1. You can be explicit about it and tell the compiler "The generic `T` is of type `f32`":

```rust
let HALVING2016: When<f32> = When {
    year: 2016.0,
    month: 7.0,
    day: 9.0,
};
```

2. You can ask the compiler to work it out for you - it won't always be able to do this, and may ask you to be explicit about it, but it'll probably work for your case. We do this by using an underscore (`_`) instead of a type, which is saying to the compiler "Work this out for yourself" (more formally called inference):

```rust
let HALVING2016: When<_> = When {
    year: 2016.0,
    month: 7.0,
    day: 9.0,
};
```

3. We can stop ascribing the type at all, and the compiler will try to do inference on the whole type (which, again, may fail and error asking you to be explicit, but I suspect it will work in this case):

```rust
let HALVING2016 = When {
    year: 2016.0,
    month: 7.0,
    day: 9.0,
};
```